# FirebaseMessagingService continuing executing before killed by swiping?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

`FirebaseMessagingService` continuing executing before killed by swiping

Don't execute

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

}
```

Comment: What is the question?